# PHP Ajax - success function if

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm having difficulty getting ajax success function to differentiate the results that come in.

```
$.ajax(
{
    type: "POST",
    url: '../ajax/ajaxLogin.php',
    data: { "username": loginUsername, "password": loginPass },
    success: function (loggedIn)
       {
           if(loggedIn == "OK") 
              {
                 window.location = 'index.php';
              } else 
              {
                 alert(loggedIn);
              }
       }
});
```

When user credentials are correct then php sends "OK" to ajax and the user should be redirected to index.php.
The result I get is always an alert. I get "OK" in alert windows as well as other messages. Whatever happens I always get something in alert window and never get redirected.
What might be wrong here?

Comment: please check the response

Comment: I used console.log(loggedIn) and all I got was OK in console.

Comment: then try if(loggedIn.trim() == "OK")

Comment: Worked like a charm! Cheers!

Comment: Accept the answer! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `if(loggedIn.trim() == "OK")`